# IE condition not working for .js and .css

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I use this code inorder to load ie.css for IE browser only. but it not work, ?I'm confused! 
Who can help me?

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Demo for IE</title>
      <!--[if IE]>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
      <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Testing for IE</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional comments are no longer supported in IE10 and IE11. So most likely, you're using either one of these versions

For your reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.aspx

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->
</head>


<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This  will apply ie.css on IE below IE9. You can change IE version.